# Send out mails to registered users after certain time period

Tags: 6

When a user registers in my site(drupal 6) they will receive a welcome mail.I would like to send out mails to registered users after some time period (say for example,2 months),so the newly registered users will receive mail after two months from their date of registration.I tried Rules module but the users receives mail as soon as they registered.Is there any module to implement this?Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [hook_cron()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) 
to send email using [drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) and then comparing current date with the published date (timestamp of two dates) in the hook_node.
If current_date is equal to (published_date + 2 months) then send email

Comment: I believe Notify module is meant for content/comment related emails as mentioned on it's project page, "The notify module allows users to subscribe to periodic emails which include all new or revised content and/or comments of specific content types".

Comment: ok i have updated the answer @amitgoyal

Comment: @harshal I guess mentioning setting up of crontab on server will be helpful too, because if tasks are supposed to trigger on fixed time drupal poorsman cron will be irregular.

Comment: how can we trigger cron at proper time ? is there any way? @arpitr

Comment: @harshal.we can run cron using the poormanscron module.@harshal,amitgoyal,arpitr.Thank you for your response